# How would I replicate this long shadow image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shadows

I've recently got into that "hipster" trend of long shadowing.  I have seen this example quite a lot, and have tried replicating it myself.  No efforts have been successful though.  And even the close ones seemed like to much work for that effect.

[image]

Main issue i'm having are the middle green triangles, and their shadows down.  If you notice they fold over the background circle, which is another issue of mine.

**How can I replicate this technique as accurately as the image?**

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? Are you looking for an automatic way to do this instead of drawing the shadow with a shape?

Comment: It's a physics issue. The shadow wouldn't 'fold down' over the edge like that. Just remove that part. Also, it appears your shadow angles aren't consistent.

Comment: No, no.  The two green triangles.  I don't understand how they got that folded effect where they meet.  And then the popup effect it has, on the bottom right; I'm guessing that part you just duplicate the layer and move it down a few pixels though.

Answer (score 4):

**Every single shape in that image is a simple shape with a gradient overlay.** The only differences are fill color and direction of the gradient, that's all.

[image: final]

[image: shape]