# Unable to achieve long shadow effect in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform, shadows, blending

I have read several guides on how to achieve the **Long Shadow** effect using Illustrator, I tried both using the **Transform Effect** and **Blend Modes**, however I fail achieve it using both.

When I try using the Transform effect, I get all copies of the fill simply duplicated with no continuity, like so:

[image: Long shadow with Transform effect]

When I try using blend modes, here what I get:
[image: Long shadow with blend modes]

An example of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: Example of long shadow]

Comment: Could you please post an example image of what you are trying achieve?

Comment: Hi, yes: http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/2013/07/longshadow.jpg

Comment: I think for the `Blend mode`, you need to enter more steps in order for the shadow to be more gradual.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would I replicate this long shadow image?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20516/how-would-i-replicate-this-long-shadow-image). Also you could reference: [How to make a graphic with long shadow?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19191/how-to-make-a-graphic-with-long-shadow) and if you search the forum for [long shadow](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=long+shadow) there are some good results.

Comment: This works I did on a Windows machine at the office, however on my mac at home I do the same steps and I get the desired long shadow effect.

Comment: Illustrator is Illustrator on either platform. There's no difference in the application based on the OS. If something works in Windows AI, it works in Mac AI.

Comment: I understand that, I just wanted to point out that on a different Ai installation, this technique works.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the blend or transform tool, try making a single object and create a gradient on it:

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's a nice workaround I know, but I prefered the other techniques since they're more accurate and dynamic I believe.

Comment: I don't see how they are accurate since they were't working.

Comment: As I stated in the original message, it does work on my mac.

Comment: This technique is good for simple shapes, but what if I want to use it for text? I would be creating a gradient for every word.

Comment: That's true. But you'd have to do that with anything you do.